# Is it possible to conditionally display some text using the StringFormat attribute?

Tags: wpf

I have a nullable field in the database, called Generation. It specifies things like "Jr.", "II" and so on. I want a mean of conditionally specifying the generation of the client, if it isn't null, otherwise not displaying it at all. I thought that the following would work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Generation, StringFormat= {0}}" />
<TextBlock Text=", " />
```

However I'm getting an error saying that "0 is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project". The field value Generation is a varchar field. Can I do what I want with the StringFormat attribute of the TextBlock class, or do I need to use a converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write this as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Generation, StringFormat={}{0}}" />
```

This is due to the nature of using the Markup Extension, which gives special meaning to `{}`.  By adding this at the beginning (when you have no text before your first format specifier), it has the effect of "escaping" the string format specification for you, similar to how `@` is used to handle string literals in C#.

Comment: It's more of an `@` than \.

Comment: @H.B. Yeah - it's kind of unique, though - but good point, it's more like `@` in that it's only used at the "beginning"